# simplifying a javascript click count menu controlling 3 individual dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 3 individual slide down menu's at the top of my page.

1. Page Menu
2. Account dropdown
3. Cart Dropdown

I've created individual open and close functions for each one

```
function menu_open(){ 
                document.getElementById("myNav_overlay").style.height = "100%";
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
                $('.menu-link').text("menu_open");
        }

   function menu_close() {
                document.getElementById("myNav_overlay").style.height = "0%";
                document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
                $('.menu-link').text("menu");
        }

        function account_open(){ 
                document.getElementById("myAccount_overlay").style.height = "100%";
                document.getElementById("myAccount").style.height = "100%";
                $('.account-link').text("person");
        }

        function account_close() {
                document.getElementById("myAccount_overlay").style.height = "0%";
                document.getElementById("myAccount").style.height = "0%";
                $('.account-link').text("person");
        }

        function cart_open(){ 
                document.getElementById("myCart_overlay").style.height = "100%";
                document.getElementById("myCart").style.height = "100%";
                $('.cart-link').text("shopping_cart");
        }

        function cart_close() {
                document.getElementById("myCart_overlay").style.height = "0%";
                document.getElementById("myCart").style.height = "0%";
                $('.cart-link').text("shopping_cart");
        }
```

and then 3 individual click count functions to determine if the menu needs to open or close.

```
    $(function() {  
    var menuclickCount = 0;
    var accountclickCount = 0;
    var cartclickCount = 0;

    $('.menu-link').click(function () {
        if(menuclickCount%2==0){
            //do when open
              menu_open();
              account_close();
              cart_close();
        }else{
             //do when closed
             menu_close();
         }
        clickCount++;
    });

    $('.account-link').click(function () {
        if(accountclickCount%2==0){
            //do when open
              account_open();
              menu_close();
              cart_close();
        }else{
             //do when closed
             account_close();
         }
        accountclickCount++;
    });


    $('.cart-link').click(function () {
        if(cartclickCount%2==0){
            //do when open
              cart_open();
              menu_close();
              account_close();
        }else{
             //do when closed
             cart_close();
         }
        cartclickCount++;
    });


});
```

This seems rather large compared to what it has to be and seems like there may be a better/simpler way of doing it.  But honestly not sure how this would typically be done.

**Is it better to leave a setup like this as is where each one is controlled individually and manually closes the other? OR, is it better to combine these into a more robust, smaller function that still controls them as needed?**

**If it is better to combine into a simpler function, how would this be done to where it still opens and closes each dropdown section?**

*I took 1 working function and duplicated it to make this work as is.  So now I'm curious to see how this compares to what is considered industry standard and practical.*

The HTML is simple....

**Menu content**

```
<div id="myNav_overlay" class="overlay_background"></div>
<div id="myNav" class="nav-overlay">
<div class="overlay-content">
MENU
</div>
</div>
```

**Account content**

```
<div id="myAccount_overlay" class="overlay_background"></div>
<div id="myAccount" class="account-overlay">
<div class="overlay-content">
ACCOUNT
</div>
</div>
```

**Cart content**

```
<div id="myCart_overlay" class="overlay_background"></div>
<div id="myCart" class="cart-overlay">
<div class="overlay-content">
CART
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into styling the example too much, using the wonder of jQuery, you can do this:

(1) On click, select all menu containers (class .ddown in my example)

(2) return all menu containers to their default height of zero *(by removing the .showMenu class with its new height)*

(3) for the clicked container only, apply a style that increases container height.

```js
$('.ddown').click(function(){
  $('.ddown').removeClass('showMenu');
  $(this).addClass('showMenu');
});
```

```css
.container{height:100px;}
.ddown{display:inline-block;width:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:hidden;}
.mnuTitle{height:20px;}
.mnuContent{height:0;background:white;}

.showMenu{height:100px;background:palegreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myNav" class="ddown">
    <div class="mnuTitle">Menu</div>
    <div class="mnuContent">
    MENU CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myAccount" class="ddown">
    <div class="mnuTitle">Account</div>
    <div class="mnuContent">
    ACCOUNT CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myCart" class="ddown">
    <div class="mnuTitle">Cart</div>
    <div class="mnuContent">
    CART CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: I like the format and simplicity of this.  My "links" are not apart of the dropdowns.  I would need this to work with isolated links.  Also, the same link needs to be able to open and close the associated dropdown.

Comment: Sure, post your code (or an equivalent, simplified, example) and we will do our best to help.